# SVG shape morphing with value and not time

Tags: html, animation, svg, snap.svg

I am creating a game using Javascript and snap.svg

I've made a lot of interfaces and UIs with snap.svg before and made extensive use of the tweening provided with the animate function. This includes animations of morphing between two shapes with the same amount of vertices. The question is, can I tween between two SVG paths using a value and not a time? I want to morph between two shapes by putting in my own interpolation value i.e. : morph(PATH_A, PATH_B, 0.76) then it should be 0.76 the way from A to B.

I feel this functionality should already exist since that's what's happening to the SVG with every time step? How do I access this lower down function?

Regards, Dale

Comment: There is a way, but it's a long while since I've played with it. I think the key is the 'status' key of an animation (which also comes through as 's' in a 'mina' method/object. http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.animate If I remember exactly, I will update. Also you could probably hack it by passing a custom easing, so rather than bounce or linear, just pass a function that returns 0.76 and a minimal duration.

Comment: Reading a bit further, try and create an animation object (maybe with Snap.animation()), and then see if you can call myanimation.status(0.76) on it. See http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.animation (and also inAmin)

Comment: You can do all this in SMIL.

Answer (score 1):

There's possible a few different slightly hacky ways to do this. Probably the simplest is to make an animation easing function return the value you want, and don't bother including a duration. So this would look a bit like the following...

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
var d1 = "M94.2,265.7L82,203.4c43.3-15.6,83.8-29.2,137.1-20.2c61.5-27.6,126.1-56.9,202.6 46.1c18.7,18.9,21.5,39.8,12.2,62.3C322.7,231.9,208.2,247.6,94.2,265.7z";

var d2 = "M179.4,83.5l62.4-11.8c15.3,43.4-76,102.6-22.6,111.5c61.5-27.6,126.1-56.9,202.6-46.1c18.7,18.9,21.5,39.8,12.2,62.3C250.6,296.7,52.4,259.2,179.4,83.5z"

var path = s.path(d1)

function animatePartial( val ) {
    var a = Snap.animation({ d: d2 }, 0, function(n) { return val })
    path.animate(a)
}

animatePartial(0.1)

setTimeout( function() { animatePartial(0.9) }, 1000 )
```

So the above example would jump to a percentage of the animation with a value between 0 and 1 being start/end.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cukwp27/8/)

Comment: This is a very interesting way to do it. If there's no other suggestions I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks :)